# AJAX responseXML error: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having the following code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
    {
        result = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        if(result)                    
           console.log(result);
        showTable(result);
        isClicked = false;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "php_includes/getResult.php?search=" + document.getElementById("search").value, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

my file will produce something like:

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>APPLES</td><td> 0000000000414</td><td>$0.79</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Apple Sauce</td><td> 0000000000528</td><td>$1.92</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Apple</td><td> 0000000000540</td><td>$0.59</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Snapple</td><td> 0000000000543</td><td>$0.69</td></tr>
```

By running the code I get the following error:

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null"
```

However, when I use the *xmlhttp.responseText* it get the result. Any idea?

This is my PHP file:

```
    $x = 1;
$count = 0;
$result2 = array();
$result .= "<search>";
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   // $class = ($x % 2 !== 0) ? 'whiteBackground' : 'graybackground';

    //echo "OOMAD INJA";
    //$name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);
    //echo "$i   $name<br/>";
    //setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
    $plu = $row["F01"];
    $result2[] = $row['F02'];
    //$result .= "<tr class='$class' onclick = 'clicked($plu);' onmouseover='ChangeColor(this, true);' onmouseout='ChangeColor(this, false);' ><td>" . $x . "</td><td class='searchtable'>" . $row["F02"] . "</td><td> " . $row["F01"] . "</td><td height= '40px'>\$" . number_format((float) $row["F30"], 2, '.', '') . "</td></tr>";
    $result .= "<tr1><td1>" . $x . "</td1><td2>" . htmlentities($row["F02"]) . "</td2><td3> " . $row["F01"] . "</td3><td4>\$" . number_format((float) $row["F30"], 2, '.', '') . "</td4></tr1>";
    $x++;
}
$result .="</search>";
echo $result;
```

Comment: why dont you put the `document.getElementById("search").value` inside a variable to check if really exist, since looks like when you trigger the function that element does not exist in the DOM

Comment: I did check that, the element exist there.

Comment: I am just simply echo the result from the php file. Is there any special tag I need to add to make sure it's an xml

Comment: did you set the headers to be xml in the php file?

Comment: yea I also added the xml tag and a root tag.

Comment: so what is the output you? `header("Content-type: text/xml");`

Comment: no i just added the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Okay you need the header to be set since you are not returning xml